# My @Input() Is Not Passing Info Through in My Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, parent-child

In my Angular2 app I have a child-component in which I'm using an @Input() to pass info from a parent component. In my parent component view/HTML I'm binding to the child component selector and passing in the info from my parent component. The parent component view code looks like this:

```
<div class="page-view">
    <div class="page-view-left">
        <admin-left-panel></admin-left-panel>
    </div>
    <div class="page-view-right">
        <div class="page-content">
            <admin-tabs></admin-tabs>
            <table-display [APICall]="accountCall"></table-display>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then, for the component file, I have this relevant code which shows a service function being called in my ngOnInit. I'm saving that in a variable "accountCall". And that's the value I'm binding in the above view in the child component selector "table-display [APICall]="accountCall":

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.accountCall = this.localAccountService.getByStage()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

Then, in the child component, called "table-display", I'm using an @Input() to pass down the "APICall" - (i.e. so it knows about it). Here's the relevant component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-display',
  templateUrl: './table-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-display.component.less']
})
export class TableDisplayComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() APICall;
```

For whatever reason, this isn't working. I'm not getting an error. I just don't get any data populated to the page.

Also, FYI, this does work when I pass the service call directly. It's just not working when I use @Input() to pass info from parent to child.

**EDIT:** 
A couple people suggested I just bind to "records", and make that the @Input() passed through to the child component, because it contains the results of the observable, rather than just the observable itself. This was a good idea. I tried implementing this, but I am getting undefined errors now - whereas I didn't when I called the service directly from the child component. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: can you post the relevant part of `table-display.component.html` where you use the `APICall`

Comment: is it all what is there in the child component `TableDisplayComponent` , just the posted code ?

Comment: No, I'm just posing the relevant info from the component.

Comment: how could you check that the APICall didnt pass to the child ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing

```
<table-display [APICall]="accountCall"></table-display>
```

Why don't you pass the data that results from the call?

```
<table-display *ngIf="records" [asyncRecords]="records"></table-display>
```

Note that accountCall is the Observable, not the result of the call.

Edit:

Based on your update, other parent components could still use this component and use whatever records they had...

```
<table-display *ngIf="records" [asyncRecords]="records"></table-display>
<table-display *ngIf="records" [asyncRecords]="data"></table-display>
<table-display *ngIf="records" [asyncRecords]="tableStuff"></table-display>
```

If the records are of a different shape, you could always pass in something else to inform the child of the format:

```
<table-display *ngIf="records" [asyncRecords]="records" [displayType]="mainRecordType"></table-display>
```

Comment: But there are different components using this child component. So I need to somehow pass in/bind to a specific component. To clarify further, each of those components is calling a separate service function.

Comment: You could pass in records from any component that makes the service call.  That being said, instead of subscribing in the parent, just the APICall to be the observable, and subscribe in the child component.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to pull in data now, but I'm getting "undefined" errors now, whereas I wasn't when calling the service directly. Any idea why?

Comment: If you're using the "records" approach, it might not be defined when you're trying to use it because it is async.  Make sure you have proper guards in your view (Elvis operator) and you null check in your component before use :)  ngOnChanges is good for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass "records" into  instead "accountCall"

Comment: This is a good idea. And it looks like data begins to come through, but I'm now getting "undefined" errors, whereas I wasn't before when I called the service directly. Any idea why?

Comment: @Muirik can you share your code. Let me have a look.